# BZip2 - What to be passed to FileOutputstream for different types of files

Tags: java, bzip2, compression

I am trying to extract a bz2 file as mentioned below, this is a test class that I wrote and I know that it is .txt file when uncompressed, but when I actually read it from the server, the uncompressed bz2 file can be anything like  html, tar,tgz or text files, how would I be able to make this code generic such that it will work for any kind of file.

I want to uncompress different files, if it is test.txt.bz2, then uncompress to test.txt and 6223.webvis.html_20130803195241.bz2 to 6223.webvis.html_20130803195241. How can I make my code generic such that it will work for these two different scenarios.

```
try{
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\test.txt.bz2");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\test.txt");
BZip2CompressorInputStream bzIn = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(in);
int buffersize = 1024;
final byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = bzIn.read(buffer))) {
out.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
out.close();
bzIn.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
throw new Error(e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Thanks,
Akshitha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BZ2 archive does not know anything about the original name. The usual way to do it is to compress `file.ext` as `file.ext.bz2`, so you get the output file name from the archive name.

```
String inFile = "test.bz2";
String outFile = inFile.substring(0, inFile.length() - 4);
// outFile == "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal pattern is a file with name x gets saved as x.bz2, so the output file name is the input file name with the last four characters removed. The only known exception is x.tar -> x.tbz (but some people use x.tar.bz2).

This means your example doesn't follow the normal pattern; otherwise it would be test.txt.bz2.

Comment: I mentioned it incorrect, I have files as below test.txt which is a bz2 archive i.e test.txt.bz2 and 123.test.html_2013.bz2 , which are different files. What should I mention as an argument to be passed in the output stream?

Comment: Since I do not believe that the uncompressed filename is 123.test.html_2013, I think you are doing it wrong and therefore have the impossible question to ask.

Comment: This is my actual file name 6223.webvis.html_20130803195241.bz2 that I was given

Comment: Talk to the guy who is giving you these file names.

Comment: I did and he mentioned that there are webvis.html files

Comment: Ok you have a local naming convention webvis.html -> garbage.webvis.html_datetime.bz2 and you asked on stackoverflow what the original name is. I would suggest you reconsider the very thing you are trying to do. You certainly can't unpack them all as webvis.html.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite follow, are you meaning we cannot uncompress usch files?

Comment: You cannot uncompress two files to the same file name for the obvious reason.

Comment: I want to uncompress different files, if it is test.txt.bz2, then uncompress to test.txt and 6223.webvis.html_20130803195241.bz2 to 6223.webvis.html_20130803195241. How can I make my code generic such that it will work for these two different scenarios.

Comment: By removing the last four characters.